How to replace instances in the collection with others?
How can I move the Icosphere to Suzanne's position, preferably taking the size into account?



I assume that you want to move the icosphere to the position of a specific object in your collection, because in your example you can see one icosphere but two Suzannes.
You can use the Sample Index node to transfer the position, rotation or scaling of another geometry.
Note, however, that you have activated the option Separate Children and deactivated Reset Children in the Collection Info node. Only then will the objects in your collection be treated as separate objects and their position retained.

With the same index that you use to query the properties, you can then remove the desired object from the collection and replace it. The Compare node helps with this.
Tip: In the Object Info node, you can also activate the As Instance option, which means that you do not need a Geometry to Instance node.
(Blender 4.1.1+)
Update: To replace all instances directly with other objects, as you added in the comments, you can use the following setup:


this is great, but how to replace all instances of the collection at once?

@StoneAlone To do this, you would have to use the Instances to Points node, then instantiate the icosphere with Instance on Points, and plug the Index node into the Index input instead of an integer value for Sample Index.
